# Liferay 6.2 Integration with Acegi security

Tags: liferay, portal

Need suggestion, we are using Liferay Portal 6.2 we would like to have spring security features integrated, was able find documents on Acegi security integration with Liferay portal 4.2 and 4.3 versions.

http://acegi-ext.sourceforge.net/acegi-portlet-liferay.html
When i started following same steps in Liferay 6.2, i am stuck in very first step of introducing Application context XML in web.xml inside (ROOT).Even if i set contextConfigLocation to applicationContext.xml , it is never recognised and picked.

I can see in web.xml instead of "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener" in Liferay 6.2 web.xml find "com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener".

It will be great if can get some help on this

Awaiting your response

Comment: You want to use Spring Security inside Liferay itself or inside your portlet application? In case it's the first option, what are exactly your intentions? What you think you will gain?

Comment: Our product has many web apps developed using Spring MVC and Security.Now we migrating to portal, deploying each web app as portlet.We would like to have portal authentication overriden by our own db authentication,populate SecurityContextHolder with userinfo and pass this object to each portlet deployed. To achieve this i think we need Spring security inside liferay itself

Comment: Internally inside each portlet, we read userinfo from SecurityContextHolder object.